# how to disable iad from refreshing ads once fetched

Tags: ios, iad

I need to fetch the ad only once for a screen.

How do i disable the refresh of ads.

I tried setting 'setRefreshInterval' but that crashes as it is an unrecognized selector, funny cause xcode suggests it.

so how do i disable ad from refreshing once fetched?

```
self.iAdAdView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, lxPosition, MAIN_VIEW_WIDTH, AD_VIEW_HEIGHT)];

if (&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != nil) {
    [_iAdAdView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
} else {
    [_iAdAdView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
}
[_iAdAdView setDelegate:self];
[_iAdAdView setRefreshInterval:0];
```